# How do I prevent the other lines in a line graph from greying out when hovering over one in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

In highcharts, I was able to make it so that only one of these three lines has a tooltip by disabling the mouse tracking in the series data. You will see it looks like this now. [image]

See how the top two charts are "greyed out?" I don't want that. I need to turn that off so that it looks like this. [image]

See how the top two lines are not greyed out while highlighting the bottom one. How do I do this in highcharts?

Comment: Probably what you're looking for is to set `plotOptions.series.states.inactive.enabled` to `false`; see the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.inactive)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the inactive state for line series. For example:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            inactive: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m3sbecfx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.states